# How to convert foreach variable into data values for a pie?

Tags: php

The following gives me:

```
<?php
  foreach($roles as $skill => $genderB) {
      $males = count($genderB['maschio']);
      $females = count($genderB['femmina']);
      $total = $males + $females;
      echo "<li>We have ".$total." ".$skill." teachers</li>";
  }
?>
```

We have 2 francese teachers

We have 2 chimica teachers

We have 3 fisica teachers

We have 1 scienze teachers

We have 1 inglese teachers

We have 1 spagnolo teachers

We have 1 italiano teachers

I can generate a chart using the following:

```
echo do_shortcode('[wp_charts type="pie" data="10,32,50,25,5"]');
```

I would like to get each value and show it in the chart. I know i could do:

```
echo do_shortcode('[wp_charts type="pie" data="'.$total.'"]');
```

But that won't give me each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build an array and implode it:

```
foreach($roles as $skill => $genderB) {
      $males = count($genderB['maschio']);
      $females = count($genderB['femmina']);
      $total = $males + $females;
      $data[] = $total; //add to array
      echo "<li>We have ".$total." ".$skill." teachers</li>";
}
echo do_shortcode('[wp_charts type="pie" data="'.implode(',', $data).'"]');
```

Comment: no i think it is correct, basically $data[] = $total; gives total number of fisica or francese etc and builds the pie, so it is correct